# How to display dynamic query result from listbox into datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I don't know that my question is right or not .. but i want to display data into datagridview depending on multi selection items from list box

for example

[image]

in this pic i have listbox which retrieve data from database i want to display result related to items which user select

[image]

when i select items the query must related to my selected items

my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            stringComparision += "'" + listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "',";
        }
        stringComparision = stringComparision.TrimEnd(','); 
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Territories where TerritoryName IN (" + stringComparision + ") ", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
```

but like the first pic datagridview show no data 
i used SQLServer 2008 for this

where's the wrong ? .. sorry for bad english :)

Comment: You should use `IN` operator and also this won't work, prepare just the comparision string inside loop, then give it to the command.

Comment: You are reading your database for every item, and then filling your grid for that one item. That way there can never be more than one item in your grid. Also, you are doing this for all items in your list, not only the selected items.

Comment: @Berkay can u provide me with the right code sorry ?

Comment: @oerkelens so what's the right way for do this ?

Comment: dataGridView1.Update() or refresh it

Comment: @Ramankingdom doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine strings with for loop,

```
string stringComparision = "";
for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
   DataRowView dr = listbox1.SelectedItems[i] as DataRowView;
   stringComparision += "'" + dr["TerritoryName"].ToString() + "',";
}
stringComparision = stringComparision.TrimEnd(','); // to delete last comma
```

Or you can use `linq` and `string.Format()`,

```
string stringComparision = string.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                               .Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)));
```

Choose one of them and the rest is same,

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Territories where TerritoryName IN (" + stringComparision + ") ", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
conn.Close();
```

**Test scenario**; I have listbox with items : `"test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"`

Output is:

> select * from Territories where TerritoryName IN
>   ('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5')

Hope helps,

Comment: Trim strings before add. Try the query by yourself at sql server with IN operator. @Amr

Comment: Each search term must be quoted, but ideally you would use a table valued parameter here. Also, you only want selected items, not all.

Comment: Right point. I am on mobile. Sorry for that. I will update asap. @Crowcoder

Comment: query works good in sql server like : select * from Territories where TerritoryName IN('Maadi, Helwan','Kafr El Sheikh 1')
i don't know what u mean by table valued paremeter @Crowcoder

Comment: Surround listbox items with single quotes inside for loop. @Amr

Comment: @Amr, you can google that. It is more work, but safer. If your territories come from user input at any point in your application then you have a SQL Injection issue.

Comment: @Crowcoder no this territories just came from database not depending on user input

Comment: @Amr, but how did they get into the database? What if someone created a territory named `BadTerritory); SELECT * FROM [Admin];--` (or something along those lines) You should not trust input from anywhere. Always expect malicious data.

Comment: u r right i will put it in consider i'm just beginner now but i will google it  ^_^ .. but now i have another problem that this synatax doesn't work and comparisionString is empty

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                 comparisionString = listBox1.Items[i].ToString() + ',';
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Territories where TerritoryName IN ('" + comparisionString + "') ", conn);
            what i should do :D

Comment: Then debug please. Listbox items count might be 0. And also search about "using" statements, you should also dispose your objects. @Amr

Comment: What is the count of listbox items? Does breakpoint hits inside for loop? @Amr

Comment: when i depug listbox count it gives me 38 .. the real numbers of territories

Comment: @Berkay i did this edit but comparisonstring is empty while debugging

  comparisionString "System.Data.DataRowView," string

Comment: I will correct it in 20 mins. I am on mobile now. @Amr

Comment: @Amr, try [only SelectedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of looping every item.

Comment: I am sorry but you should give specific detail. What is not working? @Amr

Comment: @Berkay stringcomparsion have : "'System.Data.DataRowView'," in debug

Comment: @Crowcoder i'm sorry i did it but i have doubt in wrong syntax and doesn't work for me .. can u post ur answer ?